# From Telerik to Kendo Treeview ItemDataBound

Tags: telerik, treeview, kendo-treeview

I am currently changing a website, where the company wants to change everything from Telerik to Kendo.

And I have now run into some troubles. In the `BindTo` method can have some mappings, and `.ItemDataBound`. And in that, you can set a `Value`. A full example is here:

```
@(Html.Kendo().TreeView()
.Name("MenuTree")
.Checkboxes(true)
.ExpandAll(true)
.DragAndDrop(false)
.Events(events => events.Select("onChecked"))
        .BindTo(enumNames, mappings =>
    {
        mappings.For<string>(binding => binding.ItemDataBound((item, menuGroup) =>
            {
                item.Text = this.GlobalResource("EnergyLine", menuGroup);
                MenuGroup result;
                Enum.TryParse(menuGroup, true, out result);
                item.Value = ((int)result).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
....
```

But Kendo does not have the attribute `Value`. What is the corresponding attribute for Kendo?

Comment: The same is for ´item.LoadOnDemand´ - I dont know what to replace this with in Kendo.

Answer (score 0):

Try `item.Id` instead of `item.Value`.